# Oracle SQL XML Functions - How to get encoding in XML Prolog?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlxml

This SQL

```
SELECT XMLRoot(XMLType('<poid>143598</poid>'), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES)
  AS xmlroot FROM DUAL;
```

generates an output  as follows

```
XMLROOT
--------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<poid>143598</poid>
```

How can get encoding in my xml prolog?

Ex - I want output to be something like

```
XMLROOT
--------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<poid>143598</poid>
```

Reference -

[Generate XML Data from the database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb13gen.htm#i1029583)

Answer (score 5):

```
select xmlroot (xmltype ('<poid>143598</poid>')
                  , version '1.0" encoding="UTF-8'
                  ) "XMLRoot"
  from dual;
```

Comment: you can not pass encoding in such a way, at least for oracle 12c

Comment: Yes you can, atleast in 11g. This is an answer from 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Weird ... but looks like version argument can have anything in it -

replace

```
version '1.0'
```

with

```
version '1.0" encoding="utf-8'
```

output

```
XMLROOT
--------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<poid>143598</poid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy but let me explain the possible logic of Oracle:

Character data are stored in database encoding by default. If you want to specify encoding then probable it is different from database encoding. OK, Let it be BLOB, i.e. octet stream represented in desired encoding. So we should use [XMLSERIALIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5033) function to create representation in any encoding (including the default DB encoding as well)

```
select  
  xmlserialize(document xmltype('<Envelop>Any UTF charachers. Tous les caractères UTF. כל תווי UTF </Envelop>') as blob encoding 'UTF-8' version '1.0')
from dual;
```

If your default DB encoding is UTF-8 then you can also wrap this call into `to_clob(…)` or even `to_char(…)` to see the result. For me

```
select  
  to_char(xmlserialize(document xmltype('<Envelop>Any UTF charachers. Tous lescaractères UTF. כל תווי UTF </Envelop>') as blob encoding 'UTF-8' version '1.0'))
from dual;
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelop>Any UTF charachers. Tous les caractères UTF. כל תווי UTF </Envelop>
```