# Add namespace in an XML doc in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, namespaces

I need to add the namespace details in the xml document.

already I have namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

and xml data in the

```
l_xmltype :=dbms_xmldom.getXmlType(l_domdoc);
```

dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_domdoc);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);

This **l_xmltype** is purely XML without namespace. how to concatinate the namespace with this **l_xmltype**. please help

Comment: `<?xml?>` is not a namespace but an optional [preamable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13743250/272735).

Comment: Hi Preamable,<DeriveCoverageRequest xmlns ="urn:XYZ:ccw:config:common:data" xmlns:ns1="urn:XYZ:ccw:config:msa:data" > is the namespace. need to concantenate with the l_xmltype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was just

```
<?xml version="1.0" stadalone="yes"?>
```

then you would've used the function [XMLROOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions225.htm).

`XMLROOT` however doesn't support the encoding tag. You could "hack" your way by using XMLROOT with the parameter value of "version" as `'1.0" encoding="utf-8'` instead of `'1.0'` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784478/oracle-sql-xml-functions-how-to-get-encoding-in-xml-prolog). That is however not recommended.

If you have access to oracle support, read the document [Doc ID 1449682.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1449682.1). Oracle suggests you to do this instead -

```
SELECT 
   XMLTYPE(
       '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' 
       || l_xmlvariable_or_column
       )
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Keep in mind that `encoding="xxxx"` in the above statement is changed automatically to the characterset requested by the client. To set it to utf-8, set the `NLS_LANG` parameter to `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: Thank you Ruudvan for your help .. this is very help ful :)